# Understanding the metric transformation under infinitesimal diffeomorphism

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, notation, action, diffeomorphism-invariance

In my general relativity course, we are discussing infinitesimal diffeomorphisms defined by $x^{\mu}\rightarrow y^{\mu}(x) = x^{\mu} + \xi^{\mu}(x)$. We have been examining how different objects transform under this. For example, the metric transformation $g_{\mu\nu}(x)dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu} \rightarrow g_{\mu\nu}(y) dy^\mu dy^\nu$ can be found via

$$g_{\mu\nu}(y) dy^\mu dy^\nu = g_{\mu\nu}(x+\xi)\frac{\partial(x+\xi)^\mu}{\partial x^\alpha} \frac{\partial (x +\xi)^\nu}{\partial x^\beta} dx^\alpha dx^\beta  \tag{1}      $$

From here, it is my understanding that we Taylor expand the expressions to get:

$$ = \left( g_{\mu\nu}(x) + \xi^\alpha \partial_\alpha g_{\mu\nu}(x)\,+\, ... \right)(\delta^\mu_\alpha + \partial_\alpha \xi^\mu ) (\delta^\nu_\beta + \partial_\beta \xi^\nu\,) \mathrm d{x^\alpha} \mathrm dx^\beta     \tag{2}$$
$$= \left( g_{\mu\nu}(x) +\, \xi^\sigma \partial_\sigma g_{\mu\nu}(x) +\, g_{\mu\sigma} \partial_\nu \xi^\sigma +\, g_{\nu\sigma} \partial_\mu \xi^\sigma\,+\,...  \right) \mathrm dx^\mu \mathrm dx^\nu \tag{ 3}$$

where the dots are just higher order terms that we can ignore. From here, one can show that the metric varies with the Lie derivative in the direction of $\xi^{\mu}$.

I am really struggling to comprehend the mathematical calculation and simplification in this problem. My specific questions are:

Q1) From (1) to (2), how does one taylor expand an expression like $\partial(x+\xi)^\mu / \partial x^\alpha$? I am having trouble understanding how one gets to the resulting expression.

Q2) From (2) to (3), I am completely lost on what was done. It seems like the kronecker delta's were applied to $\mathrm dx^\alpha \mathrm dx^\beta$. I assume they would need to be factored out of the binomial expressions, but how does that affect the other terms?

Q3) I am often confused when new indices are relabeled. What is the motivation for introducing this sigma index?

Q4) On a more conceptual note, I understand that we want to use this result to show that the action is invariant under infinitesimal diffeomorphisms. But why look at infinitesimal diffeomorphisms rather than diffeomorphisms in general?

I apologize if much of this question is trivially mathematical. I debated putting it in the Math forum but figured I'd rather get a physicist's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1) The derivative is a linear operator hence
\begin{equation}
\partial_\alpha (x+ \xi)^\mu = \partial_\alpha x^\mu + \partial_\alpha \xi^\mu = \delta^\mu_\alpha + \partial_\alpha \xi^\mu
\end{equation}
The statement that those 2 factors get Taylor expanded is actually wrong, only the first factor gets Taylor expanded.

Q2) To first order in the derivatives we have something like
\begin{equation}
(g+A)(\delta+B)(\delta+C) = g \delta \delta + A\delta \delta + gB\delta + gC\delta
\end{equation}
A bit cryptic, but it gives you the four terms considered.

Q3) There isn't really a motivation, just know that you can always relabel whenever there are contraction $\xi^\alpha \xi_\alpha = \xi^\beta \xi_\beta$. Presumably they got rid of the different $\alpha$'s and $\beta$'s and replaced it with $\sigma$'s.

Q4) For most groups used in physics the general symmetry transformation can be obtained from the infinitesimal transformation, called **generators**. Therefore, one looks at the transformation under these infinitesimal transformations and want them to be of a certain form which results in an equation to solve for these infinitesimal generators.
I think that the only necessary condition is that the group should be connected to the identity such that for generators $\xi^A$ and parameters $\epsilon_A$:
\begin{equation}
g = e^{\epsilon^A \xi_A}
\end{equation}
$A$ is not a spacetime label, but an internal index of the symmetry group. $g$ is the finite group element.

Comment: Okay I have worked out the problem with your comments and I got it to work out! Thanks! Also, I am not familiar with groups/generators. Do you know any good resources for an introduction to them?

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!
About references, most books on QFT have a part about Lie groups and their generators when introducing non-Abelian gauge theories (like Pesking & Schroeder eg.)
  
Other references may be:   

Group Theory in a Nutshell for Physicists - A. Zee    

and Symmetries, Lie Algebras and Representations - J. Fuchs (more mathematically inclined)

Comment: Just a comment but $\xi_A$ are not the generators, $\xi^A \partial_A$ is the generator. You can think of diffeos as position dependent translations,so the $\xi_A$ are not the generators themselves but spacetime dependent paramenters, exactly like in a gauge transformation.

Comment: if you tried to apply your operator g to $x^\mu$ you would get $g x^\mu = x^\mu + \epsilon^A \xi_A x^\mu + \dots$ which is not how diffeos are supposed to act on coordinates.

Comment: Well, $A$ here is read as an internal index of the symmetry group, not necessarily a spacetime index. But yes, I believe you could write $\xi^{A \mu}  \partial_\mu$ if you want to be more specific in this case instead of seeing $\xi^A$ as a generator.

Comment: For diffeos, $A$ would be another spacetime index and you would rather write it as $\omega_{\mu \nu}$ for the Lorentz group.